# NPOI / ExcelReport - WorksheetStyle, check for null or empty and default the cell with some text?

Tags: excel, format, npoi

Currently I'm using something like this to check for `0` and default it with some text:

```
WorksheetStyle NR = new WorksheetStyle("NR");
NR.NumberFormat = "[=0]\"NR\"";
Format.Add(NR);
```

How do I check for `null` or `empty` and default it with the `"NR"` text?

Thanks.